# How do I load test sequential APIs one by one using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm using Jmeter to load test an application.
No: of threads is 100.

First HTTP request is the home page.
Second HTTP request is login page where the actual login is made
.
.
n APIs are there.

and what I want to achieve is:

First 100 threads hit the home page concurrently.
Then 100 threads hit the login page concurrently.
.
.
Then 100 threads hit the nth API concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of each request which you need to execute "concurrently"
2. Set `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by` to be equal to the number of concurrent users, in your case `100`

Reference: [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)

---

Although above approach answers your question better scenario would be starting with 1 virtual user and gradually increase the load, in this case you will be able to correlate increasing load with performance metrics like Response Time, Transactions Per Second, resources consumption of the application under test, etc. as the situation when 100 users open login page and then hit "Login" button at exactly the same moment is highly unlikely to happen and well-behaved load test needs to represent real usage of the application by real users as close as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Threads number 100 ,You need to put each request with synchronizing timer under 3 controllers, See [tutorial](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2016/11/jmeter-using-synchronizing-timer-on.html?m=1)